# 502 Gateway NGINX on Static Site

Tags: google-app-engine, nginx, https

I am trying to host my site on google app engine. I have created an app.yaml file but when I **deploy**, I am getting the 502 bad Gateway.

Below is my nginx.conf file.

```
events {}

http {
    server {
        server_name ishmaelsu.com;
        access_log /error.log;

        listen 8082;
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;

        location / {
            root IshmaelSunday;
            index index.html;
        }
    }
}
```

This is my log file after running **gcloud app logs read**

[image]

After running `netstat -tulp | grep 8082`, this is what I get.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

do you have other site or service using port 8082? have you opened the port in Firewall?

You do a redirection to SSL but you don't have configuration about that.

netstat -tulp | grep 8082

Comment: I changed the port to 8083, and getting the same error. 
See, the `netstat` photo I just uploaded.

Comment: netstat -a | grep -i 8082

Comment: nestat -a | grep -i 8082 nothing happens.

nginx -t I get -bash: nginx: command not found

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/configuring-your-app-with-app-yaml

Comment: That's the instructions I have been following but it does not show how to setup a nginx file